On the uniqueness of the induced connection on the restriction bundle
Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold and let $ E\xrightarrow{\pi} M $ be a vector bundle on $ M $. Let $ {\nabla} $ be a connection on $ E\xrightarrow{\pi} M $.
I'm trying to show that given any open subset $ U $ of $ M $ there is a unique connection $ {\nabla|U} $ on the restricted bundle $ E|U\xrightarrow{\pi} U $ such that
$$
({\nabla|U})_{X|U}s|U(p) = \nabla_Xs(p)
$$
for any vector field $ X $ on $ M $, global section $ s $ of $ E\xrightarrow{\pi} M $ and point $ p\in U $.
My book claims that the uniqueness follows trivially from the following two facts:

Given two vector fields $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $ such that $ X_1\equiv X_2 $ on an open neighborhood of $ p $ then $ \nabla_{X_1}s(p) = \nabla_{X_2}s(p) $ for every global section $ s $;
Given two global sections $ s_1 $ and $ s_2 $ such that $ s_1\equiv s_2 $ on an open neighborhood of $ p $ then $ \nabla_Xs_1(p) = \nabla_Xs_2(p) $ for every vector field $ X $.

I don't get why. I would simply employ a bump function argument, but I don't know if I am missing something.

yes, bump functions to define the candidate. And the two properties to show the result is independent of the choice of extensions via bump functions.

I'll try to answer my question. I used facts 1. and 2. only to show that $ \nabla|U $ independent of the choice of the bump function used to defined it.
If I haven't made any mistakes, then uniqueness follows trivially from the definition of $ \nabla|U $: no fact 1. or 2. are needed for this.
I'm still a bit puzzled tho.
Existence
Given $ p\in U $ consider a bump function $ \psi_p\in \mathscr C^\infty(M) $ such that $ \psi_p\equiv 1 $ in a small neighborhood of $ p $ inside of $ U $ and $ \psi_p\equiv 0 $ on $ M\setminus U $.
For a (globally defined) vector field $ X\colon U\to \mathrm TU $ on $ U $ denote again with $ X $ the (locally defined) vector field $ X\colon U\to \mathrm TM $ on $ M $ obtained by identifying the $ \mathrm T_pU $s with the $ \mathrm T_pM$s. And for a (global) section $ s\colon U\to E|U $ of the restricted bundle $ E|U\xrightarrow{\pi|U} U $ on $ U $, denote also with $ s $ its extension to a smooth function $ s\colon U\to E $.
Both the products $ \psi_p X\colon U\to \mathrm TM $ and $ \psi_p s\colon U\to \mathrm E $ can be extended to smooth (global) sections $ \psi_p X\colon M\to \mathrm TM $ and $ \psi_p s\colon M\to E $ of $ \mathrm TM $ and $ E\xrightarrow\pi M $ respectively.
If $ \phi_p\in \mathscr C^\infty(M) $ is another bump function defined similarly to $ \psi_p $ then

the two vector fields $ \phi_p X $ and $ \psi_p X $ on $ M $ agree on a small open neighborhood of $ p $;
the two sections $ \phi_p s $ and $ \psi_p s $ of $ E\xrightarrow\pi M $ also agree on on a small neighborhood of $ p $.

We now put
$$
(\nabla|U)_X(s)(p) = \nabla_{\psi_p X}(\psi_p s)(p)
$$
and observe that using both points 1. and 2. we can write the chain of equivalences
$$
\nabla_{\phi_p X}(\phi_p s)(p) = \nabla_{\psi_p X}(\phi_p s)(p) = \nabla_{\psi_p X}(\phi_p s)(p) = \nabla_{\psi_p X}(\psi_p s)(p)\text{.}
$$
This shows that the definition of $ (\nabla|U)_X(s)(p) $ does not depend on the bump function.
At this point we must check that the connections axioms are satisfied. We have for $ p\in U $
$$
\begin{align}
(\nabla|U)_{hX + kY}(s)(p) &= h(p)\nabla_{g_pX}(g_p s)(p) + k(p)\nabla_{g_pY}(g_p s)(p)\\
&= k(p)(\nabla|U)_X(s)(p) + h(p)(\nabla|U)_Y(s)(p)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
(\nabla|U)_X(\alpha s + \beta t)(p) &= \alpha\nabla_{g_pX}(g_p s)(p) + \beta\nabla_{g_pX}(g_p t)(p)\\
&= \alpha(\nabla|U)_X(s)(p) + \beta(\nabla|U)_X(t)(p)
\end{align}
$$
where $ g_p $ a bump function.
Uniqueness
Suppose that $ \bigcirc|U $ is another connection on the restricted vector bundle $ E|U\xrightarrow{\pi|U} U $ such that
$$
({\bigcirc|U})_{X|U}(s|U)(p) = \bigcirc_Xs(p)
$$
whenever the symbols are well defined.
Given then a vector field $ X\colon U\to \mathrm TU $ and a section $ s\colon U\to E|U $ we have
$$
(\nabla|U)_Xs(p) = \nabla_{\psi_pX}(\psi_p s)(p) = (\bigcirc|U)_{(\psi_pX)|U}\bigl((\psi_p s)|U\bigr)(p) = (\bigcirc|U)_Xs(p)
$$
where as always $ \psi_p $ is a bump function.
